# how to change [1,2,3,4] to '1234' using python

Tags: python, string, list

How do I convert a list of `int`s to a single string, such that:

`[1, 2, 3, 4]` becomes `'1234'`
`[10, 11, 12, 13]` becomes `'10111213'`

... etc...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
''.join(map(str, [1,2,3,4] ))
```

- [`map(str, array)`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) is equivalent to `[str(x) for x in array]`, so `map(str, [1,2,3,4])` returns `['1', '2', '3', '4']`.
- [`s.join(a)`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) concatenates all items in the sequence `a` by the string `s`, for example,

  ```
  >>> ','.join(['foo', 'bar', '', 'baz'])
  'foo,bar,,baz'
  ```

  Note that `.join` can only join string sequences. It won't call `str` automatically.

  ```
  >>> ''.join([1,2,3,4])
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found
  ```

  Therefore we need to first `map` all items into strings first.

Comment: good call sir... I would have overlooked that the numbers weren't strings ;)

Answer (score 12):

```
''.join(str(i) for i in [1,2,3,4])
```