# python csv replace listitem

Tags: python, csv, listitem

i have following output from a csv file:

```
word1|word2|word3|word4|word5|word6|01:12|word8
word1|word2|word3|word4|word5|word6|03:12|word8
word1|word2|word3|word4|word5|word6|01:12|word8
```

what i need to do is change the time string like this 00:01:12.
my idea is to extract the list item [7] and add a "00:" as string to the front.

```
import csv

with open('temp', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="|")
    for row in reader:      
        fixed_time = (str("00:") + row[7])
        begin = row[:6]
        end = row[:8]
        print begin + fixed_time +end
```

get error message:

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list.

i also had a look on this post.

[how to change [1,2,3,4] to '1234' using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597932/how-to-change-1-2-3-4-to-1234-using-python/2597937#2597937)

i neeed to know if my approach to soloution is the right way. maybe need to use split or anything else for this.

thx for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line that's throwing the exception is

```
print begin + fixed_time +end
```

because `begin` and `end` are **both lists** and `fixed_time` is a string.  Whenever you take a **slice** of a list (that's the `row[:6]` and `row[:8]` parts), a list is returned.  If you just want to print it out, you can do

```
print begin, fixed_time, end
```

and you won't get an error.

#### Corrected code:

I'm opening a new file for writing (I'm calling it 'final', but you can call it whatever you want), and I'm just writing everything to it with the one modification.  It's easiest to just change the one element of the list that has the line (`row[6] here`), and use `'|'.join` to write a pipe character between each column.

```
import csv

with open('temp', 'r') as f, open('final', 'w') as fw:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="|")
    for row in reader:      
        # just change the element in the row to have the extra zeros
        row[6] = '00:' + row[6]
        # 'write the row back out, separated by | characters, and a new line.
        fw.write('|'.join(row) + '\n')
```

Comment: hi thx for help. no i need the data in the format i put it in. with | delimiter.

Comment: @Malik I've updated my answer.  Hopefully it works for you.  At any rate, I'm off to sleep now.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex for that:

```
>>> txt = """\
... word1|word2|word3|word4|word5|word6|01:12|word8
... word1|word2|word3|word4|word5|word6|03:12|word8
... word1|word2|word3|word4|word5|word6|01:12|word8"""

>>> import re
>>> print(re.sub(r'\|(\d\d:\d\d)\|', r'|00:\1|', txt))
word1|word2|word3|word4|word5|word6|00:01:12|word8
word1|word2|word3|word4|word5|word6|00:03:12|word8
word1|word2|word3|word4|word5|word6|00:01:12|word8
```

Comment: hi i thought about that soloution too. but i think regex are not the best way to fix this kind of task. correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: can you please tell me why you would prefer your way instead the above? just for interessting and learning! thx for your answer.